# Need some help with x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

```
MODRM_EAX_06 MACRO   ;/* [EAX], with reg/opcode: /6 */ 
    BYTE    030h 
ENDM
```

What does byte 030h do ?

For additional info this macro is used in

```
void vmxPtrld(u64 addr) 
VmxPtrld PROC StdCall _addr_low,_addr_high 
mov eax,8 
add eax,ebp 
vmx_ptrld 
MODRM_EAX_06 
ret 
VmxPtrld ENDP
```

I just want to understand what the macro does in the following code?

Comment: [Code that is potentially being asked about.](http://bluepillstudy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nbp-0.32-public/i386/vmx-asm.asm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many opcodes are followed by a ModR/M byte, which is split into 3 portions: the top two bits are "Mod", the next three are "Reg", and the bottom three are "R/M".

The combination of the "Mod" and "R/M" portions specify a register and addressing mode; the "Reg" portion may specify another register, or, in some cases, may specify a further extension to the opcode.

In this case, the ModR/M byte looks like this:

```
    0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
    \_/ \___/ \___/
    Mod  Reg   R/M
```

Mod bits of `00` and R/M bits of `000` mean an addressing mode of `[EAX]` (in 32-bit mode).

The remaining Reg bits are `6` in decimal.  Hence `MODRM_EAX_06`.

To fully understand what is going on in your example, you need to know what the `vmx_ptrld` macro does.  Assuming that this is indeed what @sixlettervariables found, `vmx_ptrld` produces bytes `0F C7`.

`0F` is the first byte of a two-byte opcode.  In many cases, the next byte will complete the opcode; but `C7` indicates that further bits must be read from the Reg field of the ModR/M byte to determine what the opcode is.  So the final opcode is `0F` followed by `C7` followed by the `6` from the Reg field of the ModR/M byte, written as `0F C7 /6` in Intel's manuals (which can be found [here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)).

`0F C7 /6` is `VMPTRLD`, so the real meaning of your routine is:

```
mov eax,8 
add eax,ebp 
vmptrld [eax]
ret
```

Presumably it has been written like this for the benefit of old assemblers which do not understand the (relatively recent) VMX instructions.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they're using this to generate instructions, and this is a [mod r/m byte](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0060_mod_reg_r_m_byte.htm) of an instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [bluepill](http://bluepillstudy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nbp-0.32-public/i386/vmx-asm.asm) (which I guess is the code the OP is asking about), `vmx_ptrld` is also a macro, so

```
vmx_ptrld
MODRM_EAX_06
```

is a single instruction, `MODRM_EAX_06` being the data for the instruction.

**Rationale:** *bluepill* is a PoC exploit for virtualization. When it was written, apparently the assembler that was used didn't yet support virtualization-related instructions, so they got coded inline via macros.